# How to use post_save with listener being method of a class

Tags: django, signals

Can I use post_save with the listener being a method of a class?

What I want:

```
class UpdCatalog(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="catalog/")

class SomeClass:
    def codeType(text):
        row_code = text[0], text[1]
        return row_code, row_type

    def main(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        text = ["q", "w", "e". "r"]
        row_code, row_type = codeType(text)

signals.post_save.connect(SomeClass.main, sender=UpdCatalog)
```

When I try run this code `main` isn't called. There are no errors.

When the listener is not in the class everything works fine.

Comment: BTW, why do you need a class here?

Comment: @DrTyrsa I will add more functions later. I can't answer why :) Maybe I wanted to move this class into a separate file later

Comment: You can move all the functions to a separate module. You don't need a class to do that.

Comment: @kvi Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding some inline code please use backticks "`" for formatting. See [faq on comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study the difference between function and instance method. And in your case you can use `staticmethod` decorator.

```
class SomeClass:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def main(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        text = ["q", "w", "e". "r"]
        row_code, row_type = codeType(text)
```

Comment: Now, when the "**main**" comes to call "**codeType**" i have: "NameError: global name 'codeType' is not defined"

Comment: Just add the `@staticmethod` decorator to codeType as well and call via `SomeClass.codeType`.

Comment: So, i will need to add the `@staticmethod` to all (other) functions in `SomeClass`?

Maybe I can call `post_save` without `@staticmethod`?

Comment: @kvi You can. Just don't use a class here.